# OSX Terminal/Vim Syntax Colors

Tags: bash, macos, vim, terminal, tmux

I've spent a bunch of time going over my Vim and Tmux configurations lately, trying to refine my workflow and I have come across a (small but annoying) problem that is stumping me. I am currently using OSX, but I have had the same issue with Windows' terminal/powershell.

My issue is that I am unable to change the `brown` color that appears in the default vim syntax highlighting which is used many of the languages that I write in. The color that I am speaking of can be seen in this vim colortest:

[image]

In the default OSX terminal (and in powershell) you can set the ANSI colors via terminal preferences, however, the `brown` color is not included in the GUI configuration options. This results in some ugly syntax highlighting that does not fit in with my desired color scheme:

[image]

My question is, what is the most portable way to change this default color? I would love to be able to do something in my `.vimrc` that would just work around this ugly color so I don't have to reconfigure colors for any system that I might be on, but I understand this might not be possible. Another route would be changing the syntax highlighting colors, but my investigations into that have so been unfruitful.

Thanks!

Appedix:
Colors selected in OSX profile for screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to copy a Linux /usr/share/vim/vimrc as your account .vimrc on macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the default Vim colorscheme is not  as tidy as one would hope. In this case, `Brown` is a bit of a "catchall" name that ends up being interpreted differently in different contexts.

- In GUI Vim, `Brown` refers to the "Brown" in X11's `rgb.txt`: `#A52A2A`.
- In TUI Vim with `&t_Co == 256`, you get `#af5f00`, AKA `130` in the "xterm palette".
- In TUI Vim with `&t_Co == 16` or `&t_Co == 8`, you get your terminal palette's "Yellow", AKA `3`.

By the looks of it, you seem to be affected by the second case.

While there exist ways to change the so-called "xterm palette" wholesale, you will have a hard time changing that specific color in a straightforward, non-messy way.

What you can do…

- Do `:set background=dark` to force Vim to use a different set of default colors that doesn't include "Brown".
- Choose a built-in or third-party colorscheme that doesn't use that specific color.
- Override the `Statement` highlight group as explained [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f) with whatever color you want from the [xterm palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg).

Comment: Overriding the highlight groups is what I was looking for, since it is in the `.vimrc` it means I don't have to change settings on each system I visit. Just carry around the `.vimrc`. The group that I needed to override in my case was `Constants`. For anyone else looking around, this doc has the listings/information for all the available highlight groups: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html

Comment: It's `Constant`, not `Constants`.